# A tag for differences between versions

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think we need a tag for questions about differences between anime/manga versions and even TV series/movie versions. That way it's easy to sort all of these questions without attempting to search for them. And it would be easier to implement this now rather than once we have even more questions.

I don't really know what to call it though.

Edit: To clarify, I think there should be **one** tag for all types of version comparisons. I don't want a tag for each type of comparison. Please speak up if you disagree though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, I think [variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations)(temporary prototype tag) will be a good fit for comparison questions, it can be applied to compare manga, anime and movie differences or differences between a series.

Comment: In order to write a tag use `[tag:tag-name-here]`.

Comment: @Alenanno thanx :P

Comment: I thought you had created a tag, so I retagged two question with [tag:variations]... maybe I shouldn't have done it...

Comment: @JNat You don't "create" a tag and then use it. You create a tag the moment you use it. :P

Comment: I know, the thing is that I created one without noticing it, because I thought I was simply using the one already created by you or grasshopper...

Comment: Oh ok, I see now. :)

Comment: I definitely don't find `variations` to be very clear. It wouldn't never remind me of comparisons or differences.

Comment: @Alenanno as stated its just a prototype feel free to replace it

Comment: @grasshopper It's not my decision alone. I'm trying to convince everybody about it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: **No**.

Having considered this a bit... I actually don't think we should have a tag for this.

- It serves no purpose. No one is going to follow it, or ignore it. It only makes sense as a subtag of a particular series, and it's long established on SE that such tags are a BAD thing
- It's either redundant with the title (bad), or replacing it (worse: "When Sai leaves. [hikaru-no-go](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hikaru-no-go) [variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations)").
- Fundamentally... it's a meta-tag seperating out a certain kind of QUESTION, rather than categorizing it by the OBJECT of the question. It seems like it separates around the object, but that would only be if we had tags like [hikaru-no-go-variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hikaru-no-go-variations), rather than this meta-tag bolted onto the side of the other tag.

Comment: I think variations is more appropriate

Comment: possibly... adaptations is really only appropriate for manga/novels that become anime, whereas variations encompasses things like FMA/FMA:B

Comment: indeed, but I think that is a better option. otherwise you'll end up having a 'adaptations' and a 'variations' tag. And, imo, that is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for [difference](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) or rather, [differences](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences), as usually the plural is used for tags. Well, not always, but when possible it's the preferred form.

I propose to burninate/eliminate/delete/replace the [variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations) tag since it is too unclear. And go with the one i proposed above.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, I'm thinking of something like [manga-anime-differences](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-anime-differences) or [manga-anime-variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-anime-variations). Go wild. I think it's a perfectly valid tag.

Comment: It seems a little wordy and too specific. What about TV/movie or novel/anime comparisons?

Comment: or maybe simply 'comparisons', which is broader and could be used for all those purposes. otherwise you'll have a large amount of tags that are just slightly different. IMO, that is redundant.

Comment: @atlantiza: Good point. TV/Movie is offtopic on this site. I guess [tag:anime-variation] or [tag:manga-variation] sounds acceptable

Comment: @JNat: problem is [tag:comparison] opens the door for many small tag variation, leading to some sort of god tag.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha How is it off topic? For clarification, I'm talking about a story with both a TV anime and movie anime.

Comment: @atlantiza: Oh, okay, that's different then :)