# Should there be a tag to differentiate American vs. Japanese versions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I know that for some shows, there are differences between American and Japanese versions of animes (and probably mangas as well). One of the clearest examples of this is the change in relation between people in the American version of Sailor Moon. Sometimes, the name is different (Cardcaptor Sakura vs. Cardcaptors) but not always. Should there be a tag to specify that a question is specifically asking about the American version?

I know a similar question was asking in this post: [A tag for differences between versions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/a-tag-for-differences-between-versions). That only talks about variations, though, and I wanted to specifically address changed American versions.

Comment: A better example would be *Go Lion* vs Voltron.

Comment: Or Robotech vs Macross (and the other series that were rolled into Robotech.

Answer (score 6):

I think [variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations) still can encompass this. The title and body of the question will make it clear. I'm not sure if differentiating between versions in different languages or in different media is significant enough to warrant a separate tag.